# Como consultar por el numero de la semana del año en sql?

Tags: java, sql, h2, spring-jdbc

vengo hacia ustedes porque quisiera conocer como puedo consultar en la base de datos por medio del numero de la semana, el tipo de dato es TimeStamp.

Actualmente cuento con este diseño en la base de datos. El objetivo de la consulta es retornar todos los datos que contengan el idTech y el número de la semana del año.

```
`id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
`idTech` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`idService` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
`horaInicio` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
`horaFinal` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

En el siguiente código se que estoy retornando toda la base de datos y partiendo de ahí hago las respectivas filtraciones, pero quisiera reducir y hacerlo directamente desde la base de datos.

```
public List<Tech> findTechByIdTechAndWeek(String id, int week){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TECH WHERE idTech = ?";
        String sqlFilter="SELECT * FROM TECH WHERE idTech = ? AND ()";
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,id.toString());
//            preparedStatement.setInt(2, week);
//            preparedStatement.setInt(3, week);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            List<Tech> teches = new ArrayList<>();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                Tech techFilter = getTechFromResultset(resultSet);
                if (techFilter.getHoraInicial().get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR)==week
                        && techFilter.getHoraFinal().get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR)==week) {
                    teches.add(techFilter);
                }
            }
            return teches;
        }catch (SQLException sqlException){
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Query no result by id = "+id);
        }
    }
```

Por lo cual creo que es conveniente quitar lo que se encuentra en el if, ya que no seria necesario y seria redundante.

El valor sqlFilter hace referencia a la nueva consulta que deseo realizar y retornar como tal.

Comment: El manejo de fechas depende mucho del motor de base de datos. ¿Cuál usas?. Además es esencial saber cuándo comienza la semana 1.

Comment: Pues mira, uso h2 como base de datos cierto. Entonces tengo entendido que puedo usar isoweek como para retomar la semana dentro de un año lo podria consultar y determinar en que semana esta, para despues devolver ya todo el objeto como tal y despues almacenarlo en un array

Comment: Usa esta sentencia y nos cuentas que tal te va SELECT DATENAME(ww, horaInicio)

Comment: Aquí te dejo el select completo   SELECT * FROM TECH WHERE idTech = ? AND DATENAME(ww, horaInicio)=? AND DATENAME(ww, horaFinal)=?

Comment: Hola omar, la verdad hice lo que me dijiste, pero no me funciono, de todas formas el problema ya lo solucione, hice lo siguiente. ```SELECT * FROM tech WHERE idTech=? AND (WEEK(horaInicio)=? OR WEEK(horaFinal)=?)``` donde week retorna la semana dentro de año. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.